# Strange behaviour when clicking on MathJax in question title

Tags: bug, mathjax, titles

I clicked on $\mathbb{RP}^n\times\mathbb{RP}^n$ in this title

[image]

Instead of taking me to the question, it stays on the same page but now displays this

[image]

If I click on $\mathbb{CP}^n$ instead, I go to the question itself. (Here is a link to the post: [Is there an explicit description of a cobordism between $\mathbb{CP}^n$ and $\mathbb{RP}^n\times\mathbb{RP}^n$?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/231317/is-there-an-explicit-description-of-a-cobordism-between-mathbbcpn-and-ma).)

To test it use, e.g., the mentioned question in the list https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/cobordism

Why is this happening and can it be fixed?

Comment: Do you get the blue box or did you add that to highlight the change? For me the situation is if I click once the formula moves (and only this), if I click it again the link works and briefly the formula jumps back. (Of course this is still puzzling.)

Comment: I get the blue box.

Comment: This may have something to do with the MathJax contextual menu. On typical desktop browsers, it is activated by right click on the formula, but e.g. on mobile devices, there is no way to distinguish left and right.

Comment: The outline is caused by new behavior in MathJax 2.6 -- it adds equations to the tabindex for accessibility reasons. However, the glitch is independent of that (you can disable the tabindex behavior via the menu). You can also trigger it by right-clicking on the link's regular text and then reset the glitch by clicking elsewhere in the page. So it looks like a CSS quirk. Still, I've filed https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax/issues/1390 to take another look.